# If an Object can hold an Array, how is the Array accessed?

Tags: php

I currently have an Object which holds a series of Arrays, when I do `print_r` it does show the arrays however, when I want to get these values out I seem to be getting an error.

```
print_r($Obj->Example);
```

Returns:

```
Object => Example ( 'Username' => 'Example' )
```

My code to query through the Object is:

```
foreach($Obj as $single):
    echo $Example['Username'];
endif;
```

Is it possible to query through like this because it isn't working and I get an error saying that:

> $Obj is not defined as an Array

So how can I access the Example array and `echo` all the *Usernames* ?

Comment: try this `$Exampale->username` and use `var_dump()` function for dumping variable. don't use `print_r`

Comment: Please show us your *real* output from `print_r()`

Comment: @Naumov Besides that variables are case-sensitive, why shouldn't OP use `print_r()`?

Comment: you can foreach objects, but they have to implement [iterable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). without that, you can NOT use foreach on an object, because it's NOT an array.

Comment: `print_r()` returns me what I am looking for and it is an array but when I `foreach` the Object to get to the `Array` it gives me an error. How do I `foreach` the Object?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it like that and more simpler, wouldn't it be: `foreach($Obj->Example as $row): echo $row['Username']; endif;` ??????

Comment: @KyleE4K Show us your real and full output, right now you don't show us an actual output from `print_r()` and without that we can't know what structure  of objects and arrays you have

Comment: @Rizier123 because `print_r ` output readable variables, and `var_dump` dump information about variable http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Sorry @Rizier123, my Arrays held sensitive data so I didn't want to actually provide the actual output. I did say it was what was expected and was correct. I just didn't know how to go about iterating, either go through the object to get it or just do: `$Obj->Example` but the comments widened how I pictured doing this. Thanks though!

Comment: @Rizier123 for example http://ibin.co/2ZteiKJZc9RU

Comment: Yes, mine looked very similar but contained functions xD The Object was an Instance of a Class. `$Obj` represented my Class instance and `Example` is actually an Array of peoples emails so I just didn't want to show this data. @Rizier123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Example` is an array that belongs to an object, the code would be like this

```
foreach($Obj->Example as $single):
    echo $single['Username'];
endif;
```

Comment: Yeah, after reading the comments I kinda widened the way I was looking at this concept. I can't iterate through the Object to get to the Array, I'd have to declare that I wanted to iterate through the Array **inside** my Class the Object. Thanks for this! I'll mark it when I can! Finally, I can *instance* and use the Arrays inside it! xD